# Webpack is hoisting/encapsulating my code when bundle/mini (build) with JavaScript packages

Tags: webpack, bundler, bundling-and-minification, webpack-4

I'm running in an issue with webpack when i'm bundling/minifying my javascript files.

My package looks like this:

```
var myPackage = (function () {
    return {

        myFunction: function() {

        }
    }
})(this);
```

Once I build with Webpack the result is somewhat like this

```
(function(modules) {
        // some webpack function
})({

    function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

      // some webpack stuff`

            var myPackage = (function() {

         return {

             // my functions

          }

          })(undefined);

    }
});
```

As you can see my package has been hoisted/encapsulated and makes it impossible to read my functions. So for example: myPackage.test() does not exists / is unreachable and thus it cannot be executed

Any one having the same problem or used to have it and solved?

Comment: There are some errors in your code (first example), perhaps it is just incomplete Please fix them.

Comment: @mbuechmann thanks for your response i'm 100% convinced that my code works.  My guess is that you're talking about the return before I calling myFunction(). I have tested it before building with webpack and it works fine (also, there is no mistake in the first example).

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about the return you just added. Glad it works now

Comment: Uhmm.. nothing has changed... It's is not a an issue with my code... The problem is whenever webpack bundles, minify, compress my package it is unreachable.

Comment: It is unclear what `this` contains. Do you need this param?

Comment: Do you mean `myPackage.myFunction()` instead of `myPackage.test()`?

Comment: You have to be aware of the concept of a module and what webpack does, it converts esm to commonjs to be able to be executed on the browser, it is normal to have all this boilerplate over your original code. Show us how you are importing this, and how you are trying to execute

Comment: I edited the code like you requested. Not in a perfect way, since this is the first time I ever asked for help, this it ain't perfect. Secondly, my code works perfect and yes I do understand how the package works. Thirdly, my problem is:" bundling, compiling and minifying with webpack." For some reason webpack hoists/encapsulates my code.

Comment: Well, only options is try to see of module concatenation is the root of your problem... try setting `optimization.concatenateModules` to false on your config. I keep thinking that it is not, but give it a shot.

Comment: If that does not works, see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment

Comment: Thanks @MatheusSilva I tried the optimization.concatenateModules without any success. The link you send seems pretty close to what I need. I will give it a try and let you know in a few minutes :)

Comment: First of all: No one is harassing you. We are just asking question, because we need clarifications, in order to answer your question. We want to help. Second: There have been errors in your code. No one is making any accusation. Correct working code just makes it easier (or even possible) to understand your problem. Third: your code is badly formatted. If you could fix that, it is easier to help you. Last: There are still open questions. If you would be so kind and edit your question accordingly, we are eager to help

Comment: Thanks @MatheusSilva for the editing suggestion. It's my first post so I am not that familiar with the stackoverflow post system.

Any how, I went over the link and tried a few things that possible could be the problem. I tried: Module Definition System and Expose via Object Assignment. Although, I do have to admit that the Expose was a bit hard to figure out so I will look into that.

Comment: For now my webpack looks as follow according to the MDS:
 output: {
    library: {
      root: __dirname + "/js/ui_login.js",
      amd: "ui",
      commonjs: "ui-login"
    },
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    filename: "[name].bundle.min.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist/js"
  },

Answer (score 1):

That your functions are not accessible per se is the idea of modules: You define modules and require them where you need them. So in your example, you would `export` the module like this:

```
// my-module.js
module.exports = {
    myFunction: function() {
      // your code here ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no need for the IIFE.

To use it in another file, you would `import` it like that:

```
var myModule = require("./path/to/my-module.js");
```

Now you can call `myModule.myFunction()` as you like.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. But the problem is not the code.... Im not sure how many times I have to tell you that. Please, if you want to understand the issue, then try to compile, bundle and minify that piece with webpack.

Comment: The problem is the misconception of modules in javascript. Defining a function or an object inside a module does not expose it globally. How to apply modules has been explained in the answer above. Please keep an open mind and reread my answer.

Comment: Your help is appreciated, but instead of me suggestion to reread your answer perhaps you should reiterate my question a few times.

As I stated before: my code works fine and perfect and does what it needs to do. The problem is BUNDLING, COMPILING AND MINIFY that code. Other online tools allow me to minify it, however, I want to to do more than that and automated.

Comment: In that case webpack works differently than other tools. The "problem" you encounter is the expeced behavior. I tried to explain that. There is nothing to fix but the way you use webpack. If other tools work differently and the way you expect then use those tools and not webpack.